# Share the JMS Queue Weblogic clusters

Tags: jms, message-queue, weblogic11g

I have configure three weblogic 10.3 cluster with two nodes for each. I need to crate some queues and share it through out the those three clusters. That mean I need to put and listen to Queues from those three clusters.

Could someone help me out. I relay appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let assume that is a three Weblogic cluster call CL1, CL2 and CL3  manage by one Weblogic admin server.

1. First I setup the JMS server and jms queues in a jms module by pointing created jms sever in CL1 cluster using weblogic admin console.
2. Then I go to the CL2 clusters,JMS Modules(Services->Messaging->JMS Modules) and create new module(CL2JMSModule) and target to CL2 .
3. Goto inside the CL2JMSModule and create a new Foreign Server module resource and cofiger it.  put the JNDI connection url: t3://:9001
4. Goto Destinations tab and create new foreign destinatins by pointing the CL1 jms queues
5. Goto Connection Factories tab and create a new con factory and point to the CL1 jms connection factory.
6. You can flow same straps to CL3 as well.
7. Restart the server and start testing. Now you should be able to access same queue from all three clusters(CL1,CL2 and CL3)